# Is there a backwards version of a ternary operator in php?

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

I am trying to assign some value to one array if a condition is true otherwise I want to assign it to another array. I know this is possible with an if statement. However, I am wondering if it can be done with the syntax of a ternary operator?

Using an if statement it would look like this

```
        if(condition){
            $foo[] = $value;
        } else{
            $bar[] = $value;
        }
```

However, my question is if it is possible to write it similar to this?

```
        ((condition) ? ($foo[]) : ($bar[])) = $value;
```

Comment: No, it is not possible. You can join variables into array and do something like: `$array[condition? 'foo': 'bar'][] = $value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can but slightly different from the way you desire, like below:

- First way is to assign value in each of the ternary blocks.

  ```
  true ? ($foo[] = $value) : ($bar[] = $value);
  ```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/2660e)

- Second way is to use [`array_push`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) like below:

  ```
  array_push(${ true ? 'foo' : 'bar' }, $value);
  ```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/0544a)

**Note:** Replace the `true` with your condition.

Answer (score 1):

A statement like this will only result in a syntax error, or a fatal error:

```php
(true ? $foo : $bar)[] = 42;
// Fatal error: Cannot use temporary expression in write contex
```

You could also try to reference the but it still won't work:

```php
$arr = true ? &$foo : &$bar;
$arr[] = 42;
// Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "&"
```

The if statement is probably your best option. However if you really want to do something like this, you could use a single associative array with `foo` and `bar` just being keys:

```php
$arr = [
    'foo' => [],
    'bar' => [],
];

$arr[true ? 'foo' : 'bar'][] = 42;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

`condition ? ($foo[] = $value) : ($bar[] = $value);`